# Three.js: move object along face normal direction

Tags: three.js

I stucked a bit.

I have a face, its center position and the face normal. I want to place another object in front of that face along the normal direction, lets say a 1 unit far. The object I want to place in front of the face, isn't rotated properly yet, thats actually another task to solve: rotate the object (plane) perpendicular to the normal of the face. Any hints for me?

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming that you have an `object` that you want to place, a `center` of the position of the object that the face belongs to, and a `face`.

You can position the object using the face's normal:

```
object.position.addVectors(center, new THREE.Vector3(1, 1, 1).multiplyScalar(1));
```

To rotate it, you can do something like:

```
object.lookAt(center);
```

Comment: `Object3D.position` is immutable, so `object.position = ` is not a valid construct in three.js.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! I just don't see in the current solution proposal, how the object is positioned along the normal direction of the face. Lets assume the ``center`` is the center of the face and I do have the ``normal vector`` as well. To rotate with ``lookAt`` is cool and working!

Comment: The normal vector of the face is a "unit vector" that represents a a one-unit long direction/ray that is going in the direction that the face is facing.

Say that in some scenario this face is pointing straight up.  It's unit vector would then be <0, 1, 0>, straight up.  If the face is at the position <10, 10, 10>, we could then calculate that two units in front of the face's position is <10, 10, 10> + 2<0, 1, 0> = <10, 12, 10>.  Does that make sense?